# Piggyback power to dual water heaters

Tags: electrical, water, heater

Can I piggyback the power to two water heaters using the same breaker by just doing a junction box and running power to each water heater? Or do I need to run seperate line from the circuit box to the second water heater on its own breaker?

I have a 40 gallon water heater now I'm going to connect another identical 40 gallon water heater to it. Was wondering if I could just piggyback from the line that is giving power now or would I have to run its own line from the breaker box? Not worried about code, worried about safety. –

Comment: Water heater breakers are usually sized for a single unit. Does yours have double the capacity? Also, are you asking about code, safety, or what? Please edit your question to clarify and add details.

Comment: Are the heaters going to be running at the same time?

Comment: Yes going to use two 40 gallon instead of getting one 80 gallon

Answer (score 2):

No. Unless for some reason the circuit for the first water heater was way over sized.

If you read the manufacturer's installation instructions for the heater, it should specify what size circuit is required.  That size is for a single unit, and cannot have any other loads on it.

Comment: The water heart calls for a 25 breaker I think I have it on a 30. Could I just take the 30 out and wire it to a 50 then piggyback to two water heaters? Or no?

Comment: @JonathanCheslock You'd have to install wire capable of carrying 50 amperes from the water heaters back to the panel (since I doubt that's already in place). Then you'd need to install individual 30 ampere circuit protection for each of the heaters.  Basically, you'd install a 50 ampere breaker in the main panel, wire large enough to handle 50 amperes from the main panel to the water heaters. Then you'd use that circuit to feed a second panel near the water heaters. Install a 30 ampere breaker for each water heater in the second panel, and run 30 ampere wire out to each water heater.